# Changing exposure time and/or sensor ISO in microsoft visual studio(xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera, android-camera2

I currently have code that takes two pictures and displays them on the main screen of the app. Is there a way that I can change the exposure from the first picture to the second picture?

Here is my code in my MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CAMERA_APP
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private bool isFirstPhotoTaken = false;
        private string[] photoPaths = new string[2];

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isFirstPhotoTaken)
            {
                var firstPhoto = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                await LoadPhotoAsync(firstPhoto);
                isFirstPhotoTaken = true;
                await Task.Delay(2000); // Delay for 2 seconds
                var secondPhoto = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                await LoadPhotoAsync(secondPhoto);
            }
            else
            {
                ResetPhotos();
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
        {
            // Canceled
            if (photo == null)
                return;

            // Save the file into local storage
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

            if (photoPaths[0] == null)
            {
                photoPaths[0] = newFile;
                MainImage1.Source = photoPaths[0]; // Show on the front page
            }
            else if (photoPaths[1] == null)
            {
                photoPaths[1] = newFile;
                MainImage2.Source = photoPaths[1]; // Show on the front page
            }
        }

        private void ResetPhotos()
        {
            isFirstPhotoTaken = false;
            Array.Clear(photoPaths, 0, photoPaths.Length);
            MainImage1.Source = null;
            MainImage2.Source = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple things given online, such as camera2API and third party libraries, but nothing has worked without error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71953493/how-to-set-exposure-on-camera2-api